# Customer ledger

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I have two tables viz., customer deposits amount - table name is "Deposits" with column names as deposit_date, deposit_amount, cust_name ; and sales to that particular customer - table name is "inv2223"
with column names - invno, invdt, totinv, cust. I need a sql server query for the output as below:

### cust_name

Date Opening Balance Deposit Amount Sales Amount Closing Balance.

---

after one customer details, another customer details to be shown.

May I once again request you to kindly arrange to share a sql server query for this.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: You haven't specified what the granularity is, are you expecting 1 row for each deposit unioned with 1 row for each invoice, or does 1 row represent a whole _day_? Also you are including concepts of _reporting_ and _visual layouts_, in SQL we return the data, how you render it should be managed by your application or user interface.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like what you are asking for is a *Running Balance*, it helps to include some example data in your post to clarify any assumptions that we might make. Today I'll make those assumptions outright, if they are wrong, please feel free to adjust this to your actual expectations.

When I am trying to build a query, I find it easiest to use a *Natural Language* approach, write the query out as if you are explaining the layout to someone verbally, then refine your definition of each column to identify the relationships between the columns.

Rather than jumping to the answer, lets do this together...
Start with the *list of fields* from this template:

- You want to `SELECT` *a list of fields* `FROM` *somewhere* `WHERE` *they match some criteria* `ORDER BY` *a list of sort columns*

Start with your list of fields:

> ### cust_name
>
> Date, Opening Balance, Deposit Amount, Sales Amount, Closing Balance.

These fields names do not match your data source and some have spaces which is not supported in SQL. You can use a [column *Alias*](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) to change the name in the output of each field, you can also use this to [reference or specify column names that have spaces](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-write-sql-queries-with-spaces-in-column-names). The syntax for escaping spaces or keywords in an alias is different in *MySQL* and *SQL Server*, so the escaping may need to be updated for your actual database.

> **SQL Server** - use *single quotes* or *square brackets* to escape a column name or alias that contains reserved keywords or spaces:
>
> ```
> SELECT field1 as [a name with spaces], field1 as 'or you can use single quotes'
> ```
>
> **MySQL** - use backticks to escape
>
> ```
> SELECT field1 as `a name with spaces`
> ```

Your natural list of field aliases with escaping is: `[cust_name], [Date], [Opening Balance], [Deposit Amount], [Sales Amount], [Closing Balance]` so now we can map these columns using our *natural* verbose language back to where the data will come from:

- `[cust_name]`: `cust_name` field from the `Deposits` table or the `cust` field from the `inv2223` table.
- `[Date]` : `deposit_date` field from the `Deposits` Table or the `invdt` from the `inv2223` table.
- `[Opening Balance]`: The balance of the customer's account immediately before this transaction. So the sum of all deposits, with the sum of all invoices/sales subtracted from the deposits.
- `[Deposit Amount]`: `deposit_amount` field from the `Deposits` table
- `[Sales Amount]`: `totinv` field from the `inv2223` table
- `[Closing Balance]`: the overall balance at the end of this transaction, so it should be the `[Opening Balance]`  with the `[Deposit Amount]` *added* to it, if the row came from the `Deposits` table, **OR** it should be the `[Opening Balance]` with the `[Sales Amount]` *subtracted* from it if the row came from the `inv2223` table.

Already we have a rough idea of how these two tables are related to each other, there is no joining in this case, the rows originate from one of two tables, they are mutually exclusive of each other.

You have mentioned that you want to sort by Customer, but you haven't mentioned the specific *order* for the fields within each customer. In financial data like this we would commonly be sorting by the *date* or point in time of each transaction. In my query *I will sort to show the most recent transaction at the top*.

If we exclude the *Balance* columns for now, because they require calculations, then we can arrange the data like this.

```
SELECT Deposits.[cust_name]
     , Deposits.deposit_date as [Date],
     , '???' as [Opening Balance]
     , Deposits.Amount as [Deposit Amount]
     , NULL as [Sales Amount]
     , '???' as [Closing Balance]
FROM Deposits
UNION ALL
SELECT inv.cust
     , inv.invdt,
     , '???' as [Opening Balance]
     , NULL as [Deposit Amount]
     , totinv as [Sales Amount]
     , '???' as [Closing Balance]
FROM inv2223 inv
ORDER BY [cust_name], [Date]
```

The tricky bit is then to apply the calculations for the balances. How you do this in an efficient manner varies for each RDBMS and can also be greatly affected by your index plans, the amount of data and what types of filters you might apply.

In a system that produces reports like this we would not normally query ALL rows, but instead you are likely to report of a specific date range. If not all of the rows are available then we can't just sum the values in the filtered result set to obtain the *balance*. If the system has partitioned the data to include *starting* or *ending* balances, then these values might also need to be consulted to compute an accurate balance.

- For this solution we will use a very inefficient sub-query to recalculate the balance for the customer for each row. It is just to show the logical process, you can optimize this yourself or post again with more details on your specific schema and RDBMS.
- I will also use a series of nested queries that would look tidier as CTEs but not enough information about the RDBMS version is available
- I am also making an assumption that the transaction dates have time resolution, down to milliseconds.

SQL Server example:

```
SELECT [cust_name], [Date], [Opening Balance], [Deposit Amount], [Sales Amount]
     , [Closing Balance] = [Opening Balance] 
                           + COALESCE([Deposit Amount],0) 
                           - COALESCE([Sales Amount],0)
FROM (
    SELECT [cust_name], [Date], [Deposit Amount], [Sales Amount]
         , [Opening Balance] = DepositTotal - SalesTotal
    FROM (
        SELECT [cust_name], [Date], [Deposit Amount], [Sales Amount]
             , DepositTotal = COALESCE((SELECT SUM(d.Amount) 
                               FROM Deposits d
                               WHERE d.cust_name = transactions.cust_name
                                 AND d.deposit_date < transactions.[Date]),0)
             , SalesTotal = COALESCE((SELECT SUM(i.totinv) 
                               FROM inv2223 i
                               WHERE i.cust = transactions.cust_name
                                 AND d.invdt < transactions.[Date]),0)
        FROM (
            SELECT Deposits.[cust_name]
                 , Deposits.[Date],
                 , Deposits.Amount as [Deposit Amount]
                 , NULL as [Sales Amount]
            FROM Deposits
            UNION ALL
            SELECT inv.cust
                 , inv.invdt,
                 , NULL as [Deposit Amount]
                 , inv.totinv as [Sales Amount]
            FROM inv2223 inv
        ) transactions
    ) transactionsTotals
) transactionsWithBalances
ORDER BY [cust_name], [Date]
```

A cleaner implementation that is semantically the same looks like this:

```
WITH transactions as (
    SELECT Deposits.[cust_name]
         , Deposits.[Date],
         , Deposits.Amount as [Deposit Amount]
         , NULL as [Sales Amount]
    FROM Deposits
    UNION ALL
    SELECT inv.cust
         , inv.invdt,
         , NULL as [Deposit Amount]
         , inv.totinv as [Sales Amount]
    FROM inv2223 inv
)
SELECT [cust_name], [Date], [Opening Balance], [Deposit Amount], [Sales Amount]
     , [Closing Balance] = [Opening Balance] 
                           + COALESCE([Deposit Amount],0) 
                           - COALESCE([Sales Amount],0)
FROM transactions 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT DepositTotal = COALESCE((SELECT SUM(d.Amount) 
                           FROM Deposits d
                           WHERE d.cust_name = transactions.cust_name
                             AND d.deposit_date < transactions.[Date]),0)
         , SalesTotal = COALESCE((SELECT SUM(i.totinv) 
                         FROM inv2223 i
                         WHERE i.cust = transactions.cust_name
                           AND d.invdt < transactions.[Date]),0)
) transactionsTotals
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT [Opening Balance] = DepositTotal - SalesTotal
) transactionsWithBalances
ORDER BY [cust_name], [Date]
```

Further optimizations really require more knowledge of the execution environment, specifically any date filters and if opening balances for a period need to be considered. The sub-queries to obtain the totals is really inefficient, I don't reccomend it in a production environment. In those cases a stored procedure or script might be more efficient if you calculate the opening balance for the customers once and join that into the results and then incrementally calculate the balances.

Hope that helps ;)

---

#### Regarding Escaping Column Names

In the *Ansi SQL Standard* suggests using double quotes (`"`) to escape column names, this works in MS SQL Server, but not in MySQL by default, you have to enable ANSI compatibility mode for the current session.

The problem with *double quotes* is that they are used to start and terminate *string literal values* in c based programming languages like *Java*, *PHP* and *C#*. This means that to embed your SQL script as *string literal* in these languages you will need to *escape* your escape characters... It is an unfortunate situation that comes up often enough that it is easier to not use double quotes in your SQL, instead use the escape character that is compatible with both your chosen database engine *and* your application language.

Comment: Your above query with CTE is working fine but opening balance is showing NULL.  opening balance is 1739.80 as on 2022-04-01.

Comment: It's just a guide, without having the schema and data available, however I added in some `COALESCE` statements to avoid the opening `null`